# Vector Input Using Scanf (C language)

Tags: c, validation, input, vector, scanf

First time user of stackoverflow, but long time visitor. I thought it would be prudent to start being more involved. But first, I have a small question :)

Basically what I'm trying to do is take in 3 numbers (can be positive, negative or decimal) each separated by a space (X Y Z) using scanf only and be placed into an array/struct (ignoring the spaces), and returning an error message if the user does not input explicitly numbers or input them in an incorrect format. Is this possible with scanf? What is the alternative?

I've searched around at all the different questions asked but I couldn't find an answer that I could understand (first timer with C). A link, explanation or a little bit of example code would be GREATLY appreciated :)

Comment: start by writing a short program....

Comment: I havent got anything at the moment because I was unsure you could even do this with scanf in the first place - when I get home ill attempt to get jonathans solution to work and post some feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you want the three numbers to be on one line; having them spread over multiple lines would not be acceptable.  You've not indicated what should happen if there's a fourth number on the line.

Using plain `scanf()`, it is difficult, if not impossible, to control this.  Using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` it is feasible:

```
char line[4096];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
{
    double v1, v2, v3;
    if (sscanf(line, "%g %g %g", &v1, &v2, &v3) != 3)
        ...format error...
    ...save v1, v2, v3 into your structure or array...
}
```

Optionally, you can find out where the conversion finished and check that there was no debris on the line after the three numbers.